# Parse a nested JSON using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{
    "Response": {
        "MetaInfo": {
            "Timestamp": "2011-11-21T14:55:06.556Z"
        },
        "View": [
            {
                "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
                "ViewId": 0,
                "Result": [
                    {
                        "Relevance": 0.56,
                        "MatchQuality": {
                            "Country": 1,
                            "State": 1,
                            "County": 1,
                            "City": 1,
                            "PostalCode": 1
                        },
                        "Location": {
                            "LocationType": "point",
                            "DisplayPosition": {
                                "Latitude": 50.1105,
                                "Longitude": 8.684
                            },
                            "MapView": {
                                "_type": "GeoBoundingBoxType",
                                "TopLeft": {
                                    "Latitude": 50.1194932,
                                    "Longitude": 8.6699768
                                },
                                "BottomRight": {
                                    "Latitude": 50.1015068,
                                    "Longitude": 8.6980232
                                }
                            },
                            "Address": {
                                "Country": "DEU",
                                "State": "Hessen",
                                "County": "Frankfurt am Main",
                                "City": "Frankfurt am Main",
                                "District": "Frankfurt am Main",
                                "PostalCode": "60311",
                                "AdditionalData": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "Germany",
                                        "key": "CountryName"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the postal code from the above JSON. I am using gson to parse it. I am very new to JSON and from what i read from all the posts here(some very similar to this), I understood that the fields name should be as it is. So I understand i have to make 4 classes viz Response, view, Result and Address. I made them static nested classes, but I am only getting null value as output. In the next JSON, I have multiple addresses. But I am stuck on this single response.

For a short example, I try to retrieve Timestamp with this code, but it gives me a null value

```
public class ParseJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("try.json"));

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Pojo pojo = gson.fromJson(br,Pojo.class);
        System.out.println(Pojo.Response.MetaInfo.Timestamp);
        br.close();
    }
}

class Pojo {
    public Pojo() { }

    static class Response{
        static class MetaInfo {
            static public String Timestamp;

            public String getTimestamp() {
                    return Timestamp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am struggling with this, if someone can help me i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you only need the `"PostalCode"`, you could use `JsonParser` instead of having a bunch of classes:

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject address = jsonParser.parse(json)
    .getAsJsonObject().get("Response")
    .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("View").get(0)
    .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("Result").get(0)
    .getAsJsonObject().get("Location")
    .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("Address");
String postalCode = address.get("PostalCode").getAsString();
```

or for all results:

```
JsonArray results = jsonParser.parse(json)
        .getAsJsonObject().get("Response")
        .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("View").get(0)
        .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("Result");
for (JsonElement result : results) {
    JsonObject address = result.getAsJsonObject().get("Location").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("Address");
    String postalCode = address.get("PostalCode").getAsString();
    System.out.println(postalCode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also, I was curious, this should work for multiple Addresses also, right?

Comment: @sid: Great. You mean multiple results? You can iterate over `getAsJsonArray("Result")` that's what you mean.

Comment: yes, I have items which are arrays containing addresses and I need the postal code from all the addresses. I didn't quite get what do you mean by iterating over getAsJsonArray("Result").

Comment: @sid: I updated my answer to demonstrate what I mean by iterate

Comment: One of the best example available on web for Gson parsing.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a similar way to check the null element before to read it? may be some of the element might not present in json, and better to check nulls then fetch it?

Answer (score 12):

To make your Timestamp example work, try:

```
public class ParseJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("try.json"));

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Pojo pojo = gson.fromJson(br, Pojo.class);

        System.out.println(pojo.Response.MetaInfo.Timestamp);
        br.close();
    }
}

class Pojo {
    Response Response = new Response();
}

class Response {
    MetaInfo MetaInfo = new MetaInfo();
}

class MetaInfo {
    String Timestamp;
}
```

Comment: @sid: you did `Pojo...` not `pojo...` - please try this one - it works for me and should for you as well

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer for question than the other.